# Почему у меня показывается дизайн как на Windows XP, хотя я использую Windows 11 (python, Qt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

Доброго времени суток!

После установки нужных мне библиотек (pyqt5, qt5-tools) и запуска приложения на Qt5 у меня показывается дизайн окна, как на Windows XP, хотя я использую Windows 11.

Это в Qt Designer:
[image: Это в Qt Designer]

А это приложение запущенное через python:
[image: А это приложение запущенное через python]

Из .ui в .py я использовал `pyuic5 -x "account_manager.ui" -o "design.py"`

Я хочу, чтобы у меня был такой же дизайн приложения, как и в Qt Designer.

`account_manager.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>552</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>471</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Account manager</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="documentMode">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="title">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Comfortaa</family>
        <pointsize>28</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
        <kerning>true</kerning>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="mouseTracking">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Account manager</string>
      </property>
      <property name="textFormat">
       <enum>Qt::AutoText</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="ScrollArea">
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="account_area">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>460</width>
         <height>371</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>16777215</width>
            <height>48</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true"/>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>6</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>2</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>5</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>2</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>5</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QCheckBox" name="run_account_check_box">
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="login">
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <pointsize>8</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true"/>
             </property>
             <property name="placeholderText">
              <string>Login</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="password">
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <pointsize>8</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="placeholderText">
              <string>Password</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="runButton">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>16777215</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <pointsize>9</pointsize>
               <weight>50</weight>
               <bold>false</bold>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
              <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="layoutDirection">
              <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="autoFillBackground">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Run</string>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="delete_account">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>30</width>
               <height>30</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>30</width>
               <height>30</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Century</family>
               <pointsize>8</pointsize>
               <weight>50</weight>
               <bold>false</bold>
               <stylestrategy>PreferDefault</stylestrategy>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="acceptDrops">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">color: red; text-align: center;</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>❌</string>
             </property>
             <property name="icon">
              <iconset theme="❌">
               <normaloff>.</normaloff>.</iconset>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>40</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="select_all">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Select all</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="deselect_all">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Deselect all</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="add_new_account">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="cursor">
             <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Add new accaunt</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="import_accounts_from_file">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Import accaunts from file</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="save_accounts">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Save accaunts</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="open_config_folder">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Open config folder</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="run_all_selected">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="cursor">
             <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Run all selected</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="close_all">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="cursor">
             <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Close all</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Попробуйте: `app.setStyle('WindowsVista')`

Comment: я не знаю, как в питоне с деплоем, но в плюсах это означало что не хватает длл-ки

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я не деплоил. Это обычный запуск .py скрипта

Comment: значит что-то в окружении настроено неправильно и не подхватывается нужная либка

Comment: @BeardedBeaver а какие надо?

Comment: Григорий Власов,  пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш модуль `account_manager.ui` и лучше расскажите что именно не так у вас отображается.

Comment: @S.Nick `account_manager.ui` добавил. Посмотрите внимательнее на скрины

Comment: @zed не помоголо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне подошёл только `Fusion` стиль (были ещё `Windows`, `WindowsXP`, `WindowsVista`).

Он ставится так: `app.setStyle("Fusion")`.

Нашёл нужную информацию [здесь](https://overcoder.net/q/2479923/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-qstyle-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-pyqt).